# My question is downvoted but the self-answer is upvoted; should I delete the question?

Tags: support, questions, self-answer, vote-to-delete

I have posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25683642/build-page-containing-abandoned-products-in-opencart-on-passing-registered-em). I have tried my best to explain what I need that is not available out of the box, and that I need to implement something new. But I received a series of downvotes, and then the question was closed as "unclear what I am asking". I have added a comment asking for downvoters to explain, but did not get any helpful result.

Now, I have solved my problem and posted an answer that got upvoted!

Should I delete this question? If I try to do so, the system warns me that I should not do that, as it has an answer. But still I think that will be helpful for someone. Please suggest: in these type of scenarios, what is the ideal action to take?

After posting this, I have received more downvotes on both the question and answer. Please help me learn how to post a good question, by adding a comment.

Comment: You should edit the question to make it clearer what you're actually asking.

Comment: @Servy, i might not have skill to ask clear question, yes, may be your comment proves that, i have updated the question. Are you asking me to modify this question in MetaStackexachange? Thanks!

Comment: adding a list of requirements does make it clearer, but also too broad perhaps

Comment: @ArindamNayak No, not your meta question.  If your SO question is closed as unclear, edit it to clarify the question.  That's the whole point of the closure.

Comment: @Servy , i have just updated the question.

Comment: @ArindamNayak Did you click the link in the close box on your question? The one that says "How to Ask" takes you to a page that gives you great tips on how to ask your question. At the bottom of that "How to Ask" page, there are links to more helpful resources so that you can better learn how to ask questions and not get them closed. As for downvotes after posting this question, that's what we call the meta effect. You brought attention to your question and answer by posting a link to it on Meta SO. As people view it, they vote based on the quality of the question.

Comment: @Kendra  , i got your point completely. As far I remember,I have not clicked in close box on my question.

Comment: @ArindamNayak I suggest checking that page out. It won't give you specific help on the question at hand, but it will give you some great general guidelines. Try applying those guidelines to your question and see if you can make it a little clearer that way. :)

Comment: @ArindamNayak I noticed you have some code in the comments of that question that you had tried. It might help if you add that to your question, along with an explanation of why it wasn't working or any errors you were receiving.

Comment: @Kendra , Thanks for reminding me that, i was about to do that right now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deleting your down-voted questions counts against you as far as a question ban goes, even if you don't have a positively scored answer on it.  This implies that deleting down voted questions is officially discouraged.

Instead, you should see if you can edit the question so that it's more presentable, but beyond that, you shouldn't worry so much about the downvotes and internet points.

Comment: After posting this to Meta Forum and from suggestions, i have modified my original question in SO, i think, it makes more sense now, and as per your answer, i should keep as it is, right?

Comment: @ArindamNayak I'm not familiar with `opencart`, so I don't know whether or not your question needs more editing, but if people found your answer helpful, you don't need to delete it.

Comment: @ArindamNayak I suggested an edit that I feel helps a little bit with reability, but there's more work you can do to that question. For instance, showing some code that you had tried before you found your answer would help to show what you had tried, and might show what you're trying to do.

Comment: "deleting down voted questions is officially discouraged"  Yet there's a badge for that.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/38/peer-pressure

Comment: @Ray That badge can also be earned by deleting an answer.

Comment: "Deleting your down-voted questions counts against you as far as a question ban goes" does not necessarily lead me to conclude that deleting down-voted questions is discouraged. It's the posting of poor quality questions which is discouraged and that would be why they count towards a ban whether deleted or not.

Comment: If it's true that deleting your downvoted questions counts against you, then this is a BUG.  If someone has posted a bad question and it's been downvoted, then surely it's good for them to delete it?

Comment: *screams internally* Stack Exchange sites are not forums, even Metas..

Comment: Yes they are.  They are forums.  They are not Forums.

Comment: What about deleting duplicate down-voted questions?