# Should I delete my self-answered question if it is unworthy?

Tags: discussion, support

One day I was stuck with a problem and tried to search Web for some time. There were no results of my interest. After many tries, I was able to solve the problem myself, and I thought that my bad luck with searching was the matter of wording, that is, if I had searched for other terms, I would find the solution much faster.

So I decided to save people's time who might have the same situation. What I did was asking a [question on SO and answering it immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36688897), [as I thought it is acceptable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/250208). The key point here is that the title and body are such that they would more likely come up in a search result if you search for what I did.

Obviously, I got downvoted. I realise that vote was casted for a reason, and I'd like to be helpful to the community. Should I simply delete [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36688897), or how do I fix it?

Comment: Deleted questions will count towards a question ban so you need to be careful about doing that.

Comment: It is certainly acceptable to answer your own question, but that question must still follow the same quality metrics as any other. In this case, I don't know anything about the technology, but I don't see any code demonstrating the problem, which I would expect with a question of this type.

Comment: Also should note that asking this here will draw more attention to the question and most likely more downvotes.

Comment: Self-answered questions almost always have a problematic question.  Yours does too, if you wouldn't have answered it then it would almost certainly be closed as off-topic with "questions seeking debugging help...".  *Some* kind of hint what you did wrong or where your mental hangup might be located, preferably a snippet of the non-working code.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276832/2675154

Comment: see also: [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/839601)